# How can I get my directive to access the controllers scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a setup like this:

```
<controller>
   <directive>
```

in my controller that has a function that returns an html string. How can I get my directive to render this by accessing the controllers scope?

Or maybe I should just put the controller in the directive?

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'DataService', function ($scope, DataService) {

    $scope.parseJson = function () {
      //returns the html
    };

}]);
```

directive

```
app.directive('Output', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<need html from controller>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        //render
        //scope.parseJson();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You ought to separate the function or even put it in its own service/factory that both controller and directive can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the isolated scope: '&' option

```
app.directive('output', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: "<div ng-bind-html='parsed'></div>",
    scope:{
      output: "&"
    },
    link: function(scope){
      scope.parsed = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.output());
    }
  };
}]);
```

Template:

```
<div output="parseJson()"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, why do you use parseJson() in the directive?

Comment: @FutuToad The reason is that the directive shouldn't be tight coupled with the controller or outer scope.

Comment: ok, I think I'm getting it, I'm actually now thinking of just using the service directly in the directive, a good idea?

Comment: @FutuToad It depends , your guiding rule should be code reusability/ testability and separation of concerns.

Comment: cool, congrats on getting to 7k btw, I know thats a special number!

Comment: 1 last thing, how would I render just the **parsed** scope var for the template as I don't want the **<div ng-bind-html** etc

Comment: something like this: `elm.text(parsed)`

Comment: like this?   **template: elm.text(parsed),**

Comment: ah in the link function :)

Answer (score 1):

The directive and the controller should be sharing the scope already. Don't bother using a template for the directive, just get the HTML string in you linking function (you already have the method call in there) and modify the element directly using element.html(). Take a look at the [element docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) for more info.

Comment: It will if you use the [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service. Just inject it into the directive. After you call element.html(htmlString), you can then call $compile(element[0])(scope) and you'll be set.

Comment: im having a hard time picking the answer, I like your approach though

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('Output', function ($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var templateString = scope.parseJson();
            var compiledTemplate = $compile(templateString)(scope);
            compiledTemplate.appendTo("TheElementYouWishtoAppendYourDirectiveTo");
        }
      };
    });
```

Comment: thanks, however for my html string passed to $compile(templateString)(scope); results in the error **TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.fn**

Comment: Are you injecting $compile into the directive?

Comment: yeah: **mymodule.directive('output', ['$sce', function ($sce,$compile) {**

Comment: running **$compile** in the console outputs: **Constructor {}**, running **$compile()** gives the error I mentioned